# Shopify: Problems Getting OAuth Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, meteor, shopify

I've retrieved the authorization code in Step 1 of OAuth without a problem, but for the life of me I can't complete a post to get the access token. I always get the same error:

`content: "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Could not find Shopify API appli... (length: 103)"`

Here's what my code looks like...Meteor.http.post is a standard post request. I've tried all sorts of combinations without any luck. I'm developing on localhost:

```
var url = 'https://' + shopName + '/admin/oauth/access_token';    
var data = { client_id: apiKey, client_secret: secret, code: code };

Meteor.http.post(url, data,
    function(error, result) {
        debugger;
    });
```

Meteor.post is a standard server-side post request [documented here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_post). I've tried params (like the Node Wrapper), an array (like PHP) and a combination of other things. I have no idea.

Is it because I'm developing on localhost and server calls require https now? Is my post data structure wrong?

Any other ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In cases like these, I take a look at the full HTTP request/response with a tool like Fiddler or Charles [http://www.charlesproxy.com/] to make sure that the request looks like what it should look like.

Comment: That error message is when your `client_id` is wrong. Double check you are using a key for a valid application.

Comment: @Samuel It's right because it's being used earlier in the process to retrieve the authorization code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said you tried params but placing the params in as data like that wouldn't work. Try this..

```
var url = 'https://' + shopName + '/admin/oauth/access_token';    
var data = { client_id: apiKey, client_secret: secret, code: code };

Meteor.http.post(url, {params:data},
    function(error, result) {
        debugger;
});
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried that combination but it works like you said, Who knows what happened because I apparently didn't try that specific approach. Wow. Anyway, thanks for the help.